# Javascript Regex giving NaN from string

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am trying to get only numbers from starting of a string.

i have following code to get numbers and text from a string.

```js
var unitData = '(135 g)'  // it may be 0.135 or .135
var unitValue = Number(unitData.match(/.?\d+\.?\d*/).toString());
var unitName = unitData.match(/[A-Za-z]+/g) || '';

console.log(unitValue);
console.log(unitName);
```

its giving `NaN` for `unitValue`. It works fine if number are on first position of  a string.

Comment: Why haven't you checked what your `unitData.match(/.?\d+\.?\d*/)` returns?

Comment: `(135` is not a number, so it is correct behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one small mistake that bracket is also picked in your regex.

It was basically returning this:

> '(135

I have updated the regex. Please try below :

```js
var unitData = '(135 g)'
var unitValue = Number(unitData.match(/\d*\.?\d+/)[0]);
console.log(unitValue);
unitData = '(.135 g)'
unitValue = Number(unitData.match(/\d*\.?\d+/)[0]);
 console.log(unitValue);
unitData = '(135.42 g)'
unitValue = Number(unitData.match(/\d*\.?\d+/)[0]);
unitName = unitData.match(/[A-Za-z]+/g) || '';

console.log(unitValue);
console.log(unitName);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `toString()` called on an array still makes very little sense there.

Comment: And now `Number` applied to an array makes no sense

Comment: its giving 135 for decimal ".135" value

Comment: Yeah agreed. Though that was not causing any issue but was of no use either. I have updated the same in my answer.

Comment: @ManishBalodia in your question there is literally NO INDICATION numbers like `.135` are supposed to be handled

Comment: @zerkms I have mention it on comments. But my code handle it.

Comment: @zerkms You are very fast in identifying issue in code even though its running fine. :D I have updated to handle array as well

Comment: @ManishBalodia handled the decimal case as well

Comment: Given `Number` is applied afterwards anyway, why not use `'[^(\\s]+'` regex at all.

Comment: @zerkms yes agree it will work assuming that it will always be number after bracket.

Comment: @zerkms I have updated my asnwer to handle both decimal scenario and normal number scenario